# Properties of Fourier transform of distributions

Tags: fourier-analysis, distribution-theory

For distributions the scaling property, $f(ax) = \frac{1}{|a|} \mathcal{F(\frac{u}{a})}$, of the Fourier transform is no longer true. Is there a source that lists which properties of the Fourier transform  remain true even for distributions and which are false?

Comment: Are you sure about the failure of the scaling property?

Comment: I agree with Guiseppe.  The scaling property is commonly exploited with Dirac delta functions.

Answer (score 2):

A notable difference is behavior at $\infty$: The Fourier transform of a function in $L^1(\mathbb R)$ vanishes at $\infty$, but for a distribution it can remain constant (like the transform of $\delta$) or even grow (like the transform of $\delta'$).

But many properties can be passed from  Schwartz functions $\varphi$ to distributions $f$, thanks to the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Tempered_distributions) $$\langle \widehat f, \varphi\rangle  = \langle  f, \widehat \varphi\rangle \tag1$$ For example, the  [scaling property](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/280706/79365) passes from $\varphi$ to $f$. Stretching $f$ on the right of (1) has the same effect as  shrinking $\widehat \varphi$ (and multiplication by some constant), which  amounts to stretching $\varphi$, which has the same effect on the left as shrinking $\widehat f$.