# Inverse Fourier transform of characteristic function

Tags: fourier-analysis, characteristic-functions

Let $Q$ be a measurable set in $\mathbb{R}^2$
Let 
\begin{equation}
1_Q(\textbf{x}) =  \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
1 & \mbox{if $\textbf{x} \in Q$},\\
0 & \mbox{otherwise},\end{array} \right. 
\end{equation}
I am looking for an expression for the inverse Fourier transform
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{F}^{-1}1_Q(\textbf{u})=h(u_1,u_2).
\end{equation}
Is it possible to write it in terms of  a 2D $\mbox{sinc}$ function?

Comment: The IFT is heavily dependent upon the shape of $Q$.

Comment: Ye, but if I scale one coordinate of Q how does it affect h? I think that if I stretch coordinate $x$ of $Q$, I should  compress $u_1$ and scale $h$ by the stretching factor.

Answer (score 2):

Answering the follow-up question in comments: Yes, the Fourier transform on 2D has certain scaling properties, [explained here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/280706/79365). The difference is that the geometry in dimensions above $1$ is much richer. In one dimension, scaling and translation suffice to transform any connected set into a standard interval such as $[-1,1]$. In $\mathbb R^2$ we have infinitely many kinds of shapes, which can not be catalogized even up to scaling/translation. For example:

- Fourier  transform of a rectangle is the product of two $\mathrm{sinc} $ functions.
- Fourier transform of a disk is a [Bessel function](http://isi.ssl.berkeley.edu/~tatebe/whitepapers/FT%20of%20Uniform%20Disk.pdf), an entirely different animal.