# Show that the Fourier transform of a radial function $ L^1 (\mathbb{R}) $ is also radial

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, fourier-analysis

How do I prove that the Fourier transform of a radial function $ f \in L^1 (\mathbb{R}) $ is also radial function? I tried by polar coordinates but I dont got.

Comment: what exactly is a radial function $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$?  It seems all $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ are "radial" to me.  Perhaps you mean $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ $n > 1$?

Comment: Well, not quite all $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$, maybe only the *even* $f$ can be construed as "radial".

Comment: f is radial when $f(x)=f (y) $ whenever $|x|=|y|$

Comment: right, so every even $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ is radial!

Answer (score 5):

Just use the definition, and the change of variable $y=-x$: 
$$\widehat f(-\xi) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)e^{2\pi i \xi x}\,dx =
-\int_{ \infty}^{-\infty} f(y)e^{-2\pi i \xi y}\,dy =  \int_{ -\infty}^{ \infty} f(y)e^{-2\pi i \xi y}\,dy = \widehat f(\xi)
 $$

Let's also consider the general case $\mathbb R^n$, instead of just $\mathbb R$.  If $A:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^n$ is an invertible linear transformation, then 
$$\widehat{f\circ A}=\frac{1}{|\det A|} \widehat f\circ (A^{-1})^* \tag1$$ 
-- see [this computation](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/280529/) where the absolute value on $\det A$ was mistakenly omitted. How does (1) relate to your question? Saying that $f$ is radial is the same as saying that $f=f\circ A$ for every orthogonal transformation $A$. For such a transformation, $(A^{-1})^*=A$ and $|\det A|=1$. Therefore, 
$$\widehat f= \widehat {f\circ A}= \widehat f\circ A  $$
which means that $\widehat f$ is radial.