# Fourier rotation theorem in higher dimensions

Tags: fourier-analysis

Let $F(\mu, \nu)$ denote the Fourier transform of $f(x,y)$, then the (2D) Fourier rotation theorem says that the Fourier transform of a rotated function $f(x \cos \theta + y \sin \theta, -x \sin \theta + y \cos \theta)$ is $$F(\mu \cos \theta + \nu \sin \theta, -\mu \sin \theta + \nu \cos \theta)$$ which is the rotated version of $F(\mu, \nu)$ by the same angle $\theta$.

I wonder if this theorem holds in higher dimensions. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does, as explained [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/280706/). Since your question is not really a duplicate, I'll put an edited version of that answer below.

> Suppose $A:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^n$ is a linear transformation. 
>   Then $\mathcal F(f\circ A)$ is computed as 
>   $$\mathcal F(f\circ A)(\xi)=\int_{\mathbb R^n} f(Ax)e^{-2\pi i \xi\cdot x}\,dx 
> =  \frac{1}{|\det A|}\int_{\mathbb R^n} f(y)e^{-2\pi i \xi\cdot A^{-1}y}\,dy
> $$
>   by the change of variables $x=A^{-1}y$. Also, $\xi\cdot A^{-1}y = ((A^{-1})^* \xi )\cdot y$ by the definition of adjoint. 
>   Therefore, 
>   $$\mathcal F(f\circ A)=\frac{1}{\det A} \mathcal{F}(f)\circ (A^{-1})^* $$
>
> If  the matrix $A$ is orthogonal (this includes rotations), then $(A^{-1})^* =A$ and $|\det A|=1$. In this special case,
>   the Fourier transform commutes with composition: $$\mathcal F(f\circ A)= \mathcal{F}(f)\circ A$$